# How to get device id for Audience Network of Facebook in Flutter?

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, dart, facebook-audience-network

Using [facebook_audience_network](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network) package of flutter I tried to integrate audience network ads to my app. But as soon as I initialize my app I get this error:

**Rewarded Ad: RewardedVideoAdResult.ERROR --> {error_message: No fill, error_code: 1001, invalidated: true, placement_id: YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID}**

According to the package:

For testing purposes you need to obtain the hashed ID of your testing device. To obtain the hashed ID:

Call `FacebookAudienceNetwork.init()` during app initialization.
Place the FacebookBannerAd widget in your app.
Run the app.
The hased id will be in printed to the logcat. Paste that onto the `testingId` parameter.

```
FacebookAudienceNetwork.init(
  testingId: "37b1da9d-b48c-4103-a393-2e095e734bd6",
);
```

**I have no idea how to get device Id, while I use real device as an emulator.**

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you solved it but if anyone else looking for the solution:

Check the Logcat in android studio, you'll see a test device id.
Also if you put your ad code like this it will also show test ad:

IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID